# CSS / SCSS - Closest Value To

Tags: css, function, sass, closest

Maybe it's a dumb question, but there is a way to get closest value to target?

Something as writing

closest(58px, 6.4vh, 2vw)

and between 6.4vh and 2vw retrieve the closest to 58px

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any runtime CSS functions for something quite like that. The most similar functions available at the moment are things like [`min`, `max` and `clamp`](https://web.dev/min-max-clamp/).

However, this effect can be achieved using javascript to find the closest of each value to your target value and set a CSS variable so you can use that value where needed:

```js
const updateFontSize = (closestTo = 58) => {
    // Create an array of sizes with their CSS value and the current calculated value.
    const sizes = [
      {
        size: '6.4vh',
        value: window.innerHeight * 0.064,
      },
      {
        size: '2vw',
        value: window.innerWidth * 0.02,
      },
  ]
  // Calculate the delta from 58
  .map((size) => ({
    ...size,
    delta: Math.abs(closestTo - size.value),
  }))
  // Order by delta ascending
  .sort((a, b) => (a.delta - b.delta));
  
  // Set the font size value to the nearest option
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--closest', sizes[0].size);
};

// Trigger immediately and on window resize
updateFontSize(58);
window.addEventListener('resize', () => updateFontSize(58));
```

```css
:root {
  --closest: 58px;
}

body {
  font-size: var(--closest);
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum
```